# Protocol buffers: read only fields?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is it possible to mark fields as read only in a .proto file such that when the code is generated, these fields do not have setters?

Comment: What target language are you having protoc generate?

Comment: I'm targeting Java and C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, I think the answer here will be "no". There's a good basic guidance rule that applies to DTOs:

- DTOs should generally be as simple as possible to convey the data for serialization in a manner well-suited to the specific serializer.
- if that basic model is sufficient for you to work with *above that layer*, then fine
- but if not: **do not fight the serializer**; instead, create a separate domain model *above* the DTO layer, and simply map between the two models before serialization or after deserialization

Or put another way: the fact that the generator doesn't want to expose read-only members is irrelevant, because if you need something exotic, you shouldn't be using the generated type outside of the code that directly touches serialization. So: in your domain type that mirrors the DTO: make it read-only *there*.

As for *why* read-only fields aren't usually a thing in serialization tools: you presumably want to be able to give it a value. Serialization tools usually want to be able to write everything they can read, and read everything they can write.

---

Minor note for completeness since you mention C#: if you are using a code-first approach with protobuf-net, it'll work fine with `{get;}`-only auto-props, and with `{get;}`-only manual props ***if*** all public members trivially map to an obvious constructor.